# Want 3rd party app to view/print PDFs in MVC

Tags: pdf, model-view-controller

Basically I am looking for a modern solution to displaying/printing PDFs. I am using a MVC website.  HTML5 support would be great.  I've looked at GroupDocs.Viewer and their newest version apparently does not have any UI support.  I've looked at Flexpaper but it doesn't seem to work properly.

I need something that is hopefully commercial and supportable, ie i can contact them and get some help.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: to be clear I don't want the user to use a client side plugin like acrobat reader, i want to be able to have a zero footprint app that displays and prints PDFs and works in modern browsers (IE11, Firefox, Chrome)

Answer (score 1):

Did you try [pdf.js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/)? It's the built-in viewer of Firefox and also embeddable into your webapps, so it looks the same on every browser.

Comment: I did not, I will do so.  Does it have a UI support?  Ie buttons to advance pages, print, etc?  Thanks!

Comment: buttons for: paging, jump to page, fullscreen, print, download, navpane, zoom, rotate

Answer (score 0):

There is GroupDocs.Viewer UI application designed to work with GroupDocs.Viewer that are available for Java and .Net 
That may be useful for you https://github.com/groupdocs-viewer/GroupDocs.Viewer-for-.NET-MVC